# Multi child in MDI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, children, mdi

I have multiple forms in MDI. I create the same child a few times, for instance 3 times. I have a data I want to send to the chosen child, but it always sends data to the latest child.

There is sample code:

```
f13 = new Excel_form(this, Convert.ToInt16(words[1].Substring(0, words[1].Length - 1)));
f13.MdiParent = this;
f13.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(f13_FormClosed);
f13.Show();
```

And function to send data:

```
f13.Odebrane(odebrane, ktory_form_pyta);
```

I want to send data to form chosen by myself. Something like this:

```
Form[] children = this.MdiChildren;
children[CHOSEN_CHILD].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

It works for WindowState, but not for sending data.
It is possible?

Comment: Is it really working for `WindowState`, or does it just appear to work because the latest child is the one being displayed?

Comment: Well...how you compute CHOSEN_CHILD?

Comment: @krillgar - it working very well for `WindowState`, Form what I Chosen is appeared. I can't get acces to function in child which I want. I have access only to the latest one.
@AdrianoRepetti - CHOSEN_CHILD is normal `int`. I have all children adresses in ARRAY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be casted to the class that Form is.

MdiChildren is a collection of "Form", that won't have the method that you are trying to use.

Something like `(children[CHOSEN_CHILD] as Excel_form).Odebrane(odebrane, ktory_form_pyta);`

Comment: You are best of the best. :D Thanks, that is the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your forms, iterate them, and find specific form by Tag.

This is how you create new childs:

```
f13 = new Excel_form(this, Convert.ToInt16(words[1].Substring(0, words[1].Length - 1)));
f13.MdiParent = this;
f13.Tag = 1; // int, string... whatever you want, Tag is object type.
f13.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(f13_FormClosed);
f13.Show();
```

Iterate and find specific one:

```
Form[] children = this.MdiChildren;
foreach (Form child in children)
{
     if(Convert.ToInt32(child.Tag) == 1) // Do something
     else // Do something else
}
```

Comment: It works the same like my example above. I want to have access to function in chosen child.
Your example don't allow me for instance: `if(Convert.ToInt32(child.Tag) == 1)
  child.Odebrane(odebrane, ktory_form_pyta);`